# Include title / salutation at /order endpoint

Tags: magento2, rest-api

Is there anyway of getting a customers title (mr / mrs etc) to the /rest/V1/orders/orderID endpoint? It currently doesn't appear.

https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html#!/salesOrderRepositoryV1

Seems like a bit of an oversight not to include this by default...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, by default, it is included. If you check thoroughly the **`response model Schema`** of **salesOrderRepositoryV1** endpoint **/V1/orders/{id}** you can find the **`"customer_prefix": "string",`** which is responsible for fetching the customer title.
This will only not show when the value is **null or empty**, otherwise it will display on response.

Comment: God I really am blind, was too caught up looking for "title" or "salutation". Thanks for this!